# R: Git + Shiny server automated deployment

Tags: r, git, shiny, shiny-server

I have a Shiny server installation, and a Git repo for my Shiny application. I develop my Shiny application and push it to the Git repo, and I would like the Shiny server to load the latest version of the application from the Git repo. How can I do this? I currently manually update the Shiny server folder for the application using a `git pull` every time that I push a new version of the application to the repo from my development machine, but I want to cut that step out of the process.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a git hook. Git hooks allow you to run a script whenever an action is completed. Inside your .git folder there's hooks folder with examples.

If you went this way, you'd probably want to use the post-receive hook which is triggered whenever you push to the repo and the server is done receiving the new commits.

You can find more information on git hooks here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Here's the part regarding post-receive hooks:

> **post-receive**
>
> The post-receive hook runs after the entire process is
> completed and can be used to update other services or notify users. It
> takes the same stdin data as the pre-receive hook. Examples include
> e-mailing a list, notifying a continuous integration server, or
> updating a ticket-tracking system – you can even parse the commit
> messages to see if any tickets need to be opened, modified, or closed.
> This script can’t stop the push process, but the client doesn’t
> disconnect until it has completed, so be careful if you try to do
> anything that may take a long time.

Here's an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/webapps/site/ || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
```

Comment: Thanks, this might take me a while to parse, but I will try it and let you know.